# Java - make new string based on old one and lag

Tags: java, string, replace, char

I need to get a new string based on an old one and a lag. Basically, I have a string with the alphabet (s = "abc...xyz") and based on a lag (i.e. 3), the new string should replace the characters in a string I type with the character placed some positions forward (lag). If, let's say, I type "cde" as my string,  the output should be "fgh". If any other character is added in the string (apart from space - " "), it should be removed. Here is what I tried, but it doesn't work :

```
String code = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd";  //my lag is 4 and I added the first 4 characters to 
char old;                                        //avoid OutOfRange issues   
char nou;
for (int i = 0; i < code.length() - lag; ++i)
{
   old = code.charAt(i);
   //System.out.print(old + " ");
   nou = code.charAt(i + lag);
   //System.out.println(nou + " ");
   //   if (s.indexOf(old) != 0)
   //   {
            s = s.replace(old, nou);
   //   }
}
```

I commented the outputs for old and nou (new, but is reserved word) because I have used them only to test if the code from position i to i + lag is working (and it is), but if I uncomment the if statement, it doesn't do anything and I leave it like this, it keeps executing the instructions inside the for statmement for code.length() times, but my string doesn't need to be so long. I have also tried to make the for statement like below, but I got lost.

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
{
  ....
}
```

Could you help me with this? Or maybe some advices about how I should think the algorithm?

Thanks!

Comment: I am curious that input String has always ordered like 'abc' and why value of lag is 4? or User can input 'dude' and output should 'evef'?

Comment: Your description is confusing. First ou say that characters should be replaced by characters placed further in the same string. Then you say that the string "cde" should be transformed to "fgh". But f, g and h are not characters of "cde". So, what do you actually want to do?

Comment: What is `s`? You don't define it in the code you posted.  Also, you say "it doesn't work", but you haven't told us *how* it doesn't work.  You need to give us a concrete example of a sample input, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: The problem is that you're replacing the same characters multiple times. Your code replaces 'a' with 'd' but later replaces that 'd' with 'g' etc. Try something more like your other loop.

Comment: If user inputs 'dude'and the output is 'evef' then the lag would be 1. Let's say that the lag is making the "dictionary". If it is 1, then a=b, b=c and so on. If it is 4, a=e, b=f, c=g and so on. But this is set at the beginning and it's static.

Comment: Do you want the sequence of letters that follows the input and the  length to be the same as the input?

Comment: @ JB Nizet - yes, I'm sorry about this. Let's say that the string "abc...xyz" it's like a dictionary and somehow the "cde" is the word you want to look for. Using the lag and the "dictionary", we should find "fgh" as "definition" for "cde"

Comment: @azurefrog s is the string that needs to be converted

Comment: OK. Then let me some time to update my answer.

Comment: @Michel For future reference you might want to read about [how to create a mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It makes it much easier for people to diagnose problems with your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because, as the [javadoc of replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) says:

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing **all** occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

(emphasis mine)

So, the first time you meet an 'a' in the string, you replace **all** the 'a's by 'd'. But then you go to the next char, and if it's a 'd' that was an 'a' before, you replace it once again, etc. etc.

You shouldn't use `replace()` at all. Instead, you should simply build a new string, using a StringBuilder, by appending each shifted character of the original string:

```
String dictionary = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.length());
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char oldChar = input.charAt(i);
    int oldCharPositionInDictionary = dictionary.indexOf(oldChar);
    if (oldCharPositionInDictionary >= 0) {
        int newCharPositionInDictionary = 
            (oldCharPositionInDictionary + lag) % dictionary.length();
        sb.append(dictionary.charAt(newCharPositionInDictionary));
    }
    else if (oldChar == ' ') {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
}
String result = sb.toString();
```

Comment: To make it more efficient, you could add string length to stringbuilder constructor.

Comment: Also if input is abcd, above will output d with lag as 3 and op wants defg?

Comment: @almasshaikh I was confused by the question. Now the the OP has clarified its problem, I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great! Sorry for not having explained too good!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Convert the string to char array.
2. iterate over each char array and change the char by adding lag
3. create new String just once (instead of loop) with new String passing char array.

   ```
   String code = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd";  
   String s = "abcdef";
   char[] ch = s.toCharArray();
   char[] codes = code.toCharArray();
   for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; ++i)
   {
     ch[i] = codes[ch[i] - 'a' + 3];
   }

   String  str = new String(ch);
   System.out.println(str);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd"; // alphabet
int N = alpha.length();
int lag = 3; // shift value

String s = "cde"; // input


StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0, index; i < s.length(); i++) {
    index = s.charAt(i) - 'a';
    sb.append(alpha.charAt((index + lag) % N));
}
String op = sb.toString(); // output
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is something like this.

It returns one more index to every character.

It reverses every String.

Have a good day!

```
package org.owls.sof;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static final String CODE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  //my lag is 4 and I added the first 4 characters to 

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("insert alphabet >> ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scanner.next();
        char[] char_arr = s.toCharArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < char_arr.length; i++){
            int order = CODE.indexOf(char_arr[i]) + 1;
            if(order%CODE.length() == 0){
                char_arr[i] = CODE.charAt(0);
            }else{
                char_arr[i] = CODE.charAt(order); 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(new String(char_arr));
        //reverse
        System.out.println(reverse(new String(char_arr)));

    }

    private static String reverse (String str) {
        char[] char_arr = str.toCharArray(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < char_arr.length/2; i++){
            char tmp = char_arr[i];
            char_arr[i] = char_arr[char_arr.length - i - 1];
            char_arr[char_arr.length - i - 1] = tmp;
        }
        return new String(char_arr);
    }
}
```